# Trying to get property 'user' of non-object

Tags: laravel

in my navbar i want to allow upload link for admin role and download for user role
i got this error ...
thats my blade.php file

```
  @if (Route::has('register'))
      @if(auth::user()->user)
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('download') }}">{{ __('download') }}</a>
          </li>
      @endif
  @else
      <li class="nav-item ">
          <a  class="nav-link capital" href="{{ route('upload') }}">{{ __('upload') }}</a>
              
          </a>
          
      @endif
      @endif
```

Comment: auth::user() will return user object. so just check auth::user() work fine

Comment: this error happens when i inter the site as guest not user or admin

Comment: yea because if you are a guest you are not authenticated, so what do you think `Auth::user()` would return when you are not authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you user is guest then you have no record on DB, so first check if has been authenticated or not.

change this line:

```
@if(auth::user()->user)
```

to this

```
@if(Auth::check())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@auth @endauth`

```php
@auth
     <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('download') }}">{{ __('download') }}</a>
     </li>
@endauth
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives

Answer (score 0):

alernative you can use `optional` global helper

```
optional(Auth::user())->$anyProperty;
```